# Expansive "sort" option in glossaries and zref package

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries, glossaries-extra, zref

I have a some important content "flying" through the document, and I want to make a list of these contents. These results are in a lot of different parts (sections, endnotes...) so, their position (and number) are changeable, in this case, a manual order is inviable.

I am trying to combine `zref` package with `\zref@extract` commands and the sort field of glossaries. The problem is that, when I put the extract commands, the glossaries package does not actualize the value, it just uses the default value and I got the wrong order.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[xindy, nomain, sanitizesort=false]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage[titleref, user, abspage]{zref}

\newcounter{test}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{test}{\arabic{test}}
\zref@addprop{main}{test}
\makeatother

\newglossary*{here}{Test}
\makeglossaries
\makeatletter
\newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}}}
\newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a2}{test}{1}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a2}{test}{1}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a2}{test}{1}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a2}{test}{1}}}
\newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a3}{test}{2}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a3}{test}{2}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a3}{test}{2}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a3}{test}{2}}}
\newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a4}{test}{3}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a4}{test}{3}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a4}{test}{3}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a4}{test}{3}}}
\newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a5}{test}{4}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a5}{test}{4}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a5}{test}{5}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a5}{test}{4}}}
\newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a6}{test}{5}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a6}{test}{5}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a6}{test}{5}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a6}{test}{5}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Here\setcounter{test}{4}\zlabel{a1}

Here\setcounter{test}{6}\zlabel{a2}

Here\setcounter{test}{10}\zlabel{a3}

Here\setcounter{test}{2}\zlabel{a4}

Here\setcounter{test}{3}\zlabel{a5}

Here\setcounter{test}{8}\zlabel{a6}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=list, nonumberlist, type=here]

\end{document}
```

Here, I get the order from the default values of `\zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}` command. I want to put the reference value (i.e., the value of the counter) on the sort engine.

I.e., with this code I got:

[image]

And I want:

```
Here 2
Here 3
Here 4 and etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your setup is that the `.aux` file, which sets the labels, is read at `begindocument`.  Hence, in the preamble, the labels are not available at all, so you get the default values in those `\zref@extractdefault` calls.

You can put them in a hook, so that the glossary entries are done when the labels are available:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[xindy, nomain, sanitizesort=false]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage[titleref, user, abspage]{zref}

\newcounter{test}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{test}{\arabic{test}}
\zref@addprop{main}{test}
\makeatother

\newglossary*{here}{Test}
\makeglossaries
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{%
  \newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a1}{test}{0}}}%
  \newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a2}{test}{1}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a2}{test}{1}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a2}{test}{1}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a2}{test}{1}}}%
  \newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a3}{test}{2}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a3}{test}{2}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a3}{test}{2}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a3}{test}{2}}}%
  \newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a4}{test}{3}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a4}{test}{3}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a4}{test}{3}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a4}{test}{3}}}%
  \newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a5}{test}{4}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a5}{test}{4}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a5}{test}{5}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a5}{test}{4}}}%
  \newglossaryentry{a\zref@extractdefault{a6}{test}{5}}{name={Here \zref@extractdefault{a6}{test}{5}},sort={a\zref@extractdefault{a6}{test}{5}},type=here, description={Here \zref@extractdefault{a6}{test}{5}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Here\setcounter{test}{4}\zlabel{a1}

Here\setcounter{test}{6}\zlabel{a2}

Here\setcounter{test}{10}\zlabel{a3}

Here\setcounter{test}{2}\zlabel{a4}

Here\setcounter{test}{3}\zlabel{a5}

Here\setcounter{test}{8}\zlabel{a6}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=list, nonumberlist, type=here]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You still got a sorting problem to solve there, since `glosarries` is sorting by the first digit, rather than considering those as numbers.  But I understand your question here was how to get the label's values, and that works as long as you query the labels after `begindocument`.

However, this seems much more suited for a ToC than for glossaries. A simple example, using `tocloft` (just an example, it does not go along with `scrbook`, but you can get equivalent functionality there):

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlistof{endoftheworldpart}{prt}{My Parts}

\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{endoftheworldpart}
  \addcontentsline{prt}{endoftheworldpart}{Here \arabic{endoftheworldpart}}}

\begin{document}

Here\mypart

Here\mypart

Here\mypart

Here\mypart

Here\mypart

Here\mypart

\listofendoftheworldpart

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The correct order for indices +10 is easy to correct, just add automatic a zero before the number 1,...,9 with `ifnumcomp` command. Also, thank for your suggestion, this will be very useful!

Comment: @TheEndofTheWorld And what happens if you hit 100? If you don't actually need the counter value to appear in your glossary entries, you could get away really easy just initializing the counter to, say, 100000.

Comment: The counter is the number of the item that I want to put in order, so it will appear in the `sort` and `description` fields. If it hit 100 (something that will be difficult to occur), I will make another workaround with `ifnumcomp`, for example,  `\ifnumcomp{x}{<}{100}{\ifnumcomp{x}{<}{10}{00x}{0x}}{x}`, I think that this is very newbie, but it solves the problem :-).

Comment: @TheEndofTheWorld Ah, if you need the counter for the description, you really have to handle it more carefully. Btw, if you happen to use the ToC alternative, I've edited the answer to use `\stepcounter` instead of `\refstepcounter`, as the latter might have some undesired side effects on your cross-references in this case. I had adapted the example from `tocloft`'s documentation, but I must have missed something on why it needed `\refstepcounter` there.